# Adobe Extension Builder, extension not found in InDesign

Tags: eclipse, adobe, adobe-indesign, complex-event-processing

I'm trying to make a POC for a future project and I've installed InDesign CC 2018, Eclipse and Adobe Extension Builder 3. I've create a new project and I only try to launch it in InDesign.

When I do "Run as" (or "Debug as") > "Indesign", InDesign is launched, but I didn't find my extension.

I have seen it's normally under "Windows" > "Extensions", but I don't have this option. I only have: "Arrange", "Workspace" and "Find extension" on Exchange (and all the other windows).

How can I launch my extension?

Comment: Did you check manifest for app versions ? InDesign CC2018 is V13 so your manifest should at very least set as  <Host Name="IDSN" Version="[13]"/> and I generally tend to set as  <Host Name="IDSN" Version="[10.0,99.9]"/> soit covers every possible further version.

Comment: I've set the version like you said, but the result is the same. I'have no "extension" sub menu under the "Windows" menu.

Comment: ho ! i found it ! thanks a lot :)